# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, routes, private

this is a custom hook that allows the user to log in dashboard page if he loggedin

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export function useAuthStatus() {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
    const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true)

    useEffect(()=>{
        const auth = getAuth()
        onAuthStateChanged(auth , (user)=>{
            if(user){
                setLoggedIn(true)
            }
            setCheckingStatus(false)
        })
        console.log("hello")

    }, [])
  return {loggedIn, checkingStatus}
}
```

and here where im use it as a private route

```
import {useAuthStatus} from '../hooks/useAuthStatus'
import { Outlet , Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
    
function PrivateRoute() {
    const {loggedIn, checkingStatus} = useAuthStatus();
    if(checkingStatus){
        return <div>looding...</div>
    }
  return loggedIn ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/auth/sign-in"/>
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array

Comment: That error could happen due to invalid router configuration, for example, infinite redirects etc. Try to isolate the piece of code that causes this issue.

Comment: Sergey points out this logic issue: If user is not-logged-in, route to `/auth/sign-in` - which undoubtedly is wrapped in your custom hook and runs the logic again - immediately looping back to `/auth/sign-in` again, round and round you go.